# Pandas create column if number is in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an existing dataframe in which I want to create a new column. The values in the new column I want to create are strings based on if an existing column contains a number in an already created list. I don't know the function to do this and keep getting errors when trying to use if statements or other pandas commands. For reference, the dataframe below is an example of what I have. If the part number matches a part number contained in a list I made, I want a color column created and to print either 'blue' or 'red' based on if the part number is in the list.

\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
part_number & color \ \hline
1            & blue  \ \hline
2            & blue  \ \hline
3            & red   \ \hline
4            & red   \ \hline
5            & blue  \ \hline
6            & red   \ \hline
7            & blue  \ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

Comment: Can you try `df['newcol'] = np.where(df['existing_column'].isin(list_you_have),"blue","red")`

Comment: Yes that worked! I kept trying to use something like below and totally forgot about the .isin function "BRC_Data['truck'] = np.where(BRC_Data.car_no in car_red, 'HFC (black)')"